# How to change the sequences of child actions in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, action

I want to generate HTML head section in a child action; while the page has many other child actions. The html head section is depended on the other actions to determine which js/css files should be included. Different child actions could share the same js/css file; and different pages have different combination of the css/js, so there is a reason to do that. Here is my sample code:

```
Layout.cshtml:
<html>
<head>
@RenderZone("header")
</head>
<body>
@RenderZone("zone1")
@RenderZone("zone2")
@RenderZone("zone3")
</html>
```

Each zone has 1 or many child actions.

The RenderZone is atually an action too. The data mode:

```
Model = GetAllChildActions(zoneName)
```

The RenderZone view:

```
foreach(var m in Model)
    @html.action(controller = m.controller, action = m.action)
```

Because the Header zone is the top so it is always executed first then it cannot get data from other child actions. I have tried filters (onActionExecuted; onActionResultExcuted and so on) but none of them works. I really need to execute the header action after all child actions are rendered. I do not want to generate the css in the bottom of a page. I could but I do not want to use javascript to inject the js/css files; or write an http module to "manually" change the output html. It is very easy to handle it in webform. I believe there is a way to do that in MVC too. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is a simple `OrderBy()` not possible?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but there is no sort available for actions (child actions) in a page. Unlike Webform which we can load user control by finding a control ID, the MVC razor does not provide a way to check a page's children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-render of all the child actions:

```
@{
    var prerender = new Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>();
    prerender["header"] = RenderZone("header");
    prerender["zone1"] = RenderZone("zone1");
}
```

And then in the body:

```
@prerender["header"]
```

This way you can have all the children perform their execution prior to rendering the first zone in your view and store the script/css registrations in the current HttpContext.

Comment: Yes it works Mr. Pre-render!! I cannot believe it is such a simple solution! It actually has another benefit that I can render the actions by looping the zone names from database. Now I can totally control the order of zone rendering based on my settings!!

By the way the data cannot be put in the parent's viewbag/data. I do not know why. In the base controller I add a test method to put data by overriding OnAction/Result Executing/ed but did not work. I put my data in the HttpContext.Items and it works out very well. 

Thank you again, so much! and thank you Seen for opening a bounty!

Comment: Good to know about the Parent ViewBag, I suspected but thought it may be possible.  HttpContext is just as good though, good call.

Comment: I modified the answer to remove the reference to the ParentActionContext ViewBag and say to use the HttpContext